# Ao adicionar função sistema não compila

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
package br.com.xti.ouvidoria.helper;

import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * @author Samuel Correia Guimarães
 */
public class ValidacaoHelper {

    /**
     * @param obj
     *            objeto a ser validado
     * @return TRUE se o objeto passado por parâmetro for NULL, VAZIO
     *         (Collections, Arrays, Strings) ou menor/igual a zero para tipos
     *         númericos
     */
    public static boolean isEmpty(Object obj) {
        boolean vazio = false;

        if (obj == null) {
            vazio = true;
        } else {
            if (obj instanceof String) {
                vazio = ((String) obj).replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().isEmpty();
            } else if (obj instanceof Number) {
                if (((Number) obj).longValue() == 0)
                    vazio = true;
            } else if (obj instanceof Collection<?>) {
                Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>) obj;
                vazio = (col == null || col.isEmpty());
            } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
                vazio = (((Object[]) obj).length == 0);
            }

        }
        return vazio;
    }

    /**
     * @param objs
     *            objetos a serem validados
     * @return TRUE se algum dos objetos passados por parâmetro for NULL ou
     *         VAZIO
     */
    public static boolean isEmpty(Object... objs) {
        boolean isEmpty = false;
        for (Object obj : objs) {
            isEmpty = isEmpty(obj);
            if (isEmpty) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return isEmpty;
    }

    /**
     * @param obj
     *            objeto a ser validado
     * @return TRUE se o objeto passado por parâmetro for diferente de NULL,
     *         VAZIO (Collections, Arrays, Strings) e maior que zero para tipos
     *         númericos
     */
    public static boolean isNotEmpty(Object obj) {
        return !isEmpty(obj);
    }
```

Queria adicionar a ela a seguinte função:

```
public static boolean saoIguais(Integer obj, Integer obj2) {
    boolean iguais = false;

    if (obj == obj2) {
        iguais = true;
    } 
    return iguais;
}
```

Porém com está o sistema nem compila!

Se eu colocar como Object no lugar de Integer ele compila:

```
public static boolean saoIguais(Object obj, Object obj2) {
    boolean iguais = false;

    if (obj == obj2) {
        iguais = true;
    } 
    return iguais;
}
```

Porém nesse caso a comparação nunca retorna como true.

Comment: Que erro e compilação ele produz?

Comment: Porque você não utiliza o método [`Object.equals(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) que já está pronto, já está na biblioteca padrão e já faz o que você quer?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Estava equivocado na minha entrada de dados por isso achei que algo estava errado

Comment: Mas o principal da minha pergunta ainda não entendi que é o pq utilizando o `(Integer obj, Integer obj2)` o sistema nem compila

Comment: E qual é o erro de compilação nesse caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O operador == em tipos não primários compara apenas a referência do objeto, não sua igualdade. Quando você faz obj1 == obj2, você esta comparando apenas se o ponteiro do obj1 aponta para o mesmo endereço de memória do obj2, independente do valor de cada um dos objetos. Para comparar igualdade, use o método equals:

```
    boolean saoIguais = obj1.equals(obj2);
```

Comment: Erro meu, o retorno de um dos objetos estava diferente dq esperava por isso do erro, com o equals comparou certo

Comment: Cuidado com os `null`s sendo passados também. É necessário verificar por eles, pois por exemplo se o 1º objeto for `null`, terá uma `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

O erro da comparação é isso mesmo que o Orlando respondeu, quando você compara um variável de de tipos complexos como os objetos você compara as suas referencias de memória. Para comparar se os valores são iguais o correto é você sobrescrever o método equals. Mas no seu caso como esta comparando um Integer ele já sobrescreve o equals e compara o conteúdo do objeto.

Peguei o seu método e fiz uma implementação com a sugestão dada e validando a nulidade do objeto:

```
    public static boolean saoIguais(Integer obj, Integer obj2) {
    //Se quiser considerar que os dois valores nulos são iguais então use o if abaixo
    if(obj == null && obj2 == null )
        return true;
    //Este if é obrigatório para validar se o objeto é nulo
    if(obj == null || obj2 == null )
        return false;
    //Compara os valores usando a implementação equal da classe Integer
    return obj.equals(obj2);
}
```