# Comparação entre Objects sempre retorna false

Tags: java, jsp, comparação

Por que mesmo com assim: `ValidacaoHelper.saoIguais(3044, 3044)`, ou seja, com parâmetros iguais, o retorno é `false`?

```
/**
 * @param obj
 *            objeto a ser validado
 * @return TRUE se o objetos passados por parâmetro forem iguais
 */
public static boolean saoIguais(Object obj, Object obj2) {
    boolean iguais = false;

    if (obj == obj2) {
        iguais = true;
    } 
    return iguais;
}
```

Comment: Para comparar objetos use instanceof

Comment: @NetinhoSantos com o instanceof não funcionou também, na verdade deu erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque `Object` é um tipo por referência, então a comparação é com os endereços dos objetos e não com os valores que estão dentro deles. Como são dois objetos diferentes, são endereços diferente, então é sempre diferente.

Veja mais em [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). É C#, mas é a mesma coisa, só que C# permite criar seus tipos por valor só Java 10 permitirá isto.

Assim funciona, mas não é do jeito que pensa, não é porque o valor é o mesmo, é porque é o mesmo objeto.

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Object x = 3044;
        Object y = x;
        System.out.println(saoIguais(x, y));
    }
    public static boolean saoIguais(Object obj, Object obj2) {
        return obj == obj2;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/t8u0VZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/arlmdqtp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/ReferenceComparison.java).

Comment: Acho que entendi, funciona como que um ponteiro

Comment: Mas sem poder fazer assim como no seu exemplo, recebendo os valores de fontes diferentes e tendo que comparar o conteúdo tem como fazer?

Comment: Tem se você receber tipos por valor e não por referência, que o o caso do `Object`. Talvez fosse o caso. Outra possibilidade é fazer um *cast*  no objeto para um tipo que permita comparar os valores mesmo, mas não faz muito sentido neste caso. AInda poderia ter um tipo específico com um método `equals()` que compare as coisas certas, mas também não parece encaixar. Pra falar a verdade não sei porque está usando um `Object`.

Comment: Nesta pergunta explico o pq: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237780/ao-adicionar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sistema-n%C3%A3o-compila